# Problems with reading in a text file, annoying error

Tags: java

I am trying to parse this text file, but I keep getting an error

> "error reading file exception"

from my code. I am looking over and over at the code and I can't see what is wrong. Any ideas as to what can be the error? I know it's not the path to were the text file is, because I made a quick easy I/O program to test it, and it worked.

```
public static List<String> parseCode() {
    List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    String File = "Sample1.txt";
    String line = null;
    try
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(File);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String add = "";

        boolean comment = false;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String [] s = line.split(" ");
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
            {
                if(s[i].contains("/*"))
                {
                    comment = true;
                }       

                if(!comment)
                {
                    add += s[i];
                    if(i < s.length-1 && add.length() > 0)
                    {
                        add += " ";
                    }

                }

                if(s[i].contains("*/"))
                {
                    comment = false;
                }
            }
            if(add.length() > 0)
            {
                inputList.add(add);
            }

            br.close();
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException E)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }
    catch(IOException E)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Reading File  Sample1.txt");
    }
    return inputList;
}
```

Comment: Please post the StackTrace.

Comment: Please read [How to create a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your code is certainly not minimal. Has the parsing something to do with the exception, or is it only the reading of lines? If it is based on the file contents, then a sample file would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `br.close();` is in the `while`-loop but should be after the loop.
This way you close the file after reading the first line.

So the fixed code (not tested) should look like this:

```
public static List<String> parseCode() {
    List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    String File = "Sample1.txt";
    String line = null;
    try
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(File);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String add = "";

        boolean comment = false;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String [] s = line.split(" ");
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
            {
                if(s[i].contains("/*"))
                {
                    comment = true;
                }       

                if(!comment)
                {
                    add += s[i];
                    if(i < s.length-1 && add.length() > 0)
                    {
                        add += " ";
                    }

                }

                if(s[i].contains("*/"))
                {
                    comment = false;
                }
            }
            if(add.length() > 0)
            {
                inputList.add(add);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException E)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }
    catch(IOException E)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Reading File  Sample1.txt");
    }
    return inputList;
}
```

Comment: doh , that was it  lol ,  thank you very much